# I need to make a opencv 64 exe ( error The procedure entry point could not be loaded )

Tags: c++, opencv, netbeans, mingw, mingw-w64

How to build a 64-bit application with mingw-w64 and opencv 64 bit dll with Netbeans IDE. I succesfully installed "mingw w64" and generated a 64 bit simple c++ exe successfully.

I tried creating a simple opencv 64 bit application by including the corresponding 64 bit dlls  to the PATH and to the NetBeans folder, but am always getting the error as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It means you're linking to an import library which declares that function/method, but the runtime library does not have it.